# Configure Nat in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: nat

I want to configure NAT for my network of 10 computers so that the data is transmitted via a single pc.

Can anyone give a good tutorial for it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NATTING in Ubuntu Server](http://askubuntu.com/questions/177985/natting-in-ubuntu-server)

Comment: @Mitch Here the OP is asking about "a good tutorial", there the question is a little bit confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/nat_iptables) is a step-by-step configuration of NAT with `iptables`:

[image: Configure Nat - 1]
[image: Configure Nat - 2]

<sup>Source: http://www.howtoforge.com/nat_iptables</sup>

Comment: This is mildly okay for RedHat/SUSE  but those aren't the right files/settings for Debian or Ubuntu.

Comment: Please don't use a screenshot of the text.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few good tutorials out there.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EasyRouter