# Can not configure eth0 and eth1

Tags: networking, ethernet, ifconfig

I have two physical networks:

eth0 192.168.0.0/24 with with several PCs and NAT adresss 192.168.0.1 where PPPoE connecting to inet;

eth1 192.168.0.1/24 with several PCs and no internet.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.2
gateway 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0

up route add -net 192.168.0.0/24 gw 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
up route add -net 192.168.1.0/24 gw 192.168.1.2 dev eth1
```

and got:

```
Reconfiguring network interfaces...RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth1.
```

what route I should add and why eth1 failed?
What default gateway I should add for 192.168.1.0/24 network?
Can anywone help?

Answer (score 0):

You should only have 1 gateway as far as I know. All traffic goes to the Internet through that interface.

```
route add default gw 192.168.0.1 eth0
```

Should be sufficient.

Although I'm not sure if it's required as you set the gateway in your eth0 config. See what the **route** command lists before you try adding it, it will probably have a default listed.

Then as long as you have IP forwarding and iptables enabled, all other computers can route through eth0 OK.

[NAT setup in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307603/configure-nat-in-ubuntu-12-04)

---

If you require 2 subnets to talk to each other then you should configure iptables to allow that traffic. Omitting one of the lines of the iptables commands should prevent traffic in both directions.

First enable ip forwarding `echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Then configure iptables.

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

To make this permanent do the following.

```
sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
```

add the line `up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat` to the bottom of /etc/network/interfaces

Then edit /etc/sysctl.conf.

```
net.ip4.ip_forward = 1
```

*You can put the iptables-save file wherever is best for you.*

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Yes, the only gatway is 192.168.0.1.

But I don't need internet in 192.168.1.0/24. Also PCs in 1.0/24 should not see PCs in 0.0/24.

When I tried to configure network without routes I can't ping anything in 192.168.1.0/24. That's why I think about route add.

Comment: Added Subnet routing to the answer. You may need to adjust the iptables commands to suit your required setup.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. So the whole setup is enable IP forwarfing and drop other traffic between subnets later? For example, if I don't need samba (Windows Networking in my case) block some ports in iptables, right?

Comment: yes, there's far too much you can do with iptables to list here. Samba is best configured to not listen on eth1 if you don't want that network to use it. "interfaces = 127.0.0.1 & bind interfaces only = yes" for e.g.

Comment: Hmmm... Still no ping from localhost to 192.168.1.100

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.1.0/24       192.168.0.0/24
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.0.0/24       192.168.1.0/24

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Comment: What I did wrong? In this case ICMP forwarding is allowed or not?

Comment: Might need further routing config, something like ` iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT` May or may not work, this is where I start to zone out! :)

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot!

PS: Sorry, it was my IP mistakes. After your instructions ICMP request to 192.168.1.200 (NAS) are going from localhost. I have also changed network mask on PC 192.168.0.5 to 255.255.0.0 and tried to send ICMP to IP adress of eth1 (192.168.1.2). Yeah, they returned from eth1!

Now looking for good advices with MASQUERADE. Can anyone help?

Comment: http://www.iptables.info/en/iptables-targets-and-jumps.html#MASQUERADETARGET - Absolutely everything you need to know about iptables.